# why is $y_p = e^{-x}(A\cos{x} + B\sin{x})$ when $F(x)=e^{-x}\cos{x}$ in non-homo linear diff eqn

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Given
$$ y''+ 4y' + 4y = e^{-x}\cos{x}$$
Find the general solution for the eqn.

My working,

$$ \lambda^2+4\lambda+4=0 $$
$$ \lambda = -2 $$
$$ y_h = C_1e^{-2x} + C_2xe^{-2x}$$

And since

$$ F(x) = e^{-x}\cos{x}$$

Which is a combination of $e^{-x}$ $ \cos{x}$, I assumed that that

$$y_p = Ae^{-x}(B\cos{x} + C\sin{x})$$

However, I am unable to proceed further, and upon checking the solution given, the actual solution assumed that 
$$y_p = e^{-x}(A\cos{x} + B\sin{x})$$

Why is that so?

Comment: Note that you wouldn't need to have an $A$ in front, inside $Ae^{-x}(B\cos x + C\sin x) = e^{-x}(AB \cos x + AC\sin x)$. Since $AB$ and $AC$ are just constants, you can just replace them with $c_1$ and $c_2$ (or $A$ and $B$) and use the trial solution that the answers used.

Comment: They’re the same thing. Think of it like this: if you had $y=ABx$, and they had $y=Ax$, can you see they’re the same?